# how to delete items from a jTable in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I have made a small program in which after pressing a button the orders made by one customer are displayed on a JTable in Java. I am using Netbeans.

The results visualized on the Table, for example of one customer, are like this:

```
Order_id    Amount
1           2500
2           3500
3           6522
```

What I want is to delete the contents of the jTable after pressing the button for displaying the data for a new Customer. How I can do that? I found one way, but the problem is that when I put the code into the button the first time that I press it; it appears an error message like if I want to delete the contents of a empty table.

In short terms, how I can do to delete the contents of a JTable by just pressing one buttom?

I have put something like this:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tOrders.getModel();
model.setRowCount(0);
```

and the error that I get, because I want to clean first the table in case that it has something is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
```

Any help?

Comment: Post some code, ideally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Describing code with words is always complex to do and hard to understand by others.

Comment: Put a check in your delete code, if == null , return..

Comment: Replace the whole `TableModel` (`JTable#setModel`) iso of trying to delete the contents

Comment: @Robin, when I put that I got the following error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set a null TableModel

Comment: @jma I never suggested to put a `null` `TableModel`. You can replace it by an empty model as you probably will have to switch models when you select a new user. But if you only need to delete, you can use the `DefaultTableModel#setRowCount(0)` method as well